# How to change button labels in jQuery UI confirmation dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to use jQuery's UI dialog box for confirmation:

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        buttons: {
            "Button One": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Button Two": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But I would like to change the button labels based on condition:

```
if (status == "active") {
    var b1 = "Red";
    var b2 = "Green";
} else {
    var b1 = "Green";
    var b2 = "Red";
}
```

Can't seem to be able to combine the two...

Comment: No, when it first opens. I change the status of a project with AJAX, which will update my db but won't refresh the page. So, if a user decides to change the status again, the labels won't make any sense...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the buttons after the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-buttons) after it has been created, by supplying a new *buttons* array.

If you change the `status` variable to anything apart from `active` in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rpKT4/) you can see the buttons get created with different labels.